# Ember 1.13.8 - {{em-form}} values not updating after clicking save

Tags: ember.js

Using the package - http://indexiatech.github.io/ember-forms. I am trying to save some information from the form

```
{{#em-form action="submit" model=model submit_button=showSubmitButton}}
   {{em-input type="text" property="username" label="username" }}
   {{em-input type="email" property="emailid" label="email" }}
   {{em-input type="password" property="password" label="password"}}
   <button class="btn btn-primary"> save </button>
{{/em-form}}
```

I am trying to save the data and it's storing the data properly in the backend. For some reason it's not clearing the form values.

Right now i am using some kind of jugaad fix to remove those values after saving the data. Any help would be great.

Comment: i looked into their page. I think you will have to manually reset your fields.

Comment: It accepts Model as param, you could probably do model=someObject. And after submit you reset someObject = > this.set('someObject, store.createRecord('somepath', {})

Comment: I tried this option, but unfortunately, i can't able to set someobject = model. If i do this way, nothing is working it's not making a call